# install just a single file with Maven?

Tags: git, maven

I'm relatively new to using Maven...and it seems everything takes a while to build, even for the smallest changes.

Question:  if I'm updating just a single file (in this case, JavaScript), is there any way to just build that single file instead of an entire module?

Example:

current command used to build is:  mvn install -pl NAME_OF_MODULE -am -Plocal,replicate

Ideal scenario, to hopefully save time:  mvn install -pl NAME_OF_MODULE/PATH_1/PATH2/FILE.JS -am -Plocal,replicate

Comment: If you want save time first measure where time leaks. Measure your build with profiler (https://github.com/jcgay/maven-profiler, https://github.com/takari/maven-profiler) and share results. It will help to invent optimization

Comment: Are you working inside an IDE ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to your question. It totally depends on your project. For example, there are three projects, named project A, project B, project C. If there is no dependecy between these projects, you can build the projects as a single. If there is a dependency, it is a little more complicated.

To answer your question, I can say, if you are sure that this javascript file is not dependent on any other file on other projects, you can simply build it by going the directory of the file (if this project has its own pom.xml) or you can build it with -pl reactor option. If you add -amd (--also-make-dependents) to -pl, it will also build its dependencies.

```
mvn install -pl project_name -amd
```

This way is more secure than others.